# Adding Labels to Scatter Smooth in R

Tags: r, scatter

I am having trouble adding data labels using the `scatter.smooth` function.

`scatter.smooth(x=PGA$DK, y=PGA$ODDS, main="PRICE ~ ODDS", )`  # scatterplot

**Data**:

```
   PLAYER         DK        ODDS 
  Rory McIlroy    10900     12 
  Dustin Johnson  11100     11 
  Tiger Woods     11300     10 
  Jon Rahm         9500     20
```

Comment: `xlab` and `ylab`? Maybe you need something else, could you please elaborate further?

Comment: I would like to have the data plots on the scatter show the name of the golfer I am plotting.

Comment: Could you add some dummy data?

Comment: PLAYER                  DK      ODDS
Rory McIlroy       10900  12
Dustin Johnson 11100 11
Tiger Woods         11300 10
Jon Rahm         9500 20

Comment: Check out the [`text`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/library/graphics/html/text.html) function

Comment: I have tried the text function but it does not seem to do anything.  I dont even get an error message: text(DK ~ODDS, labels=PLAYER, data=PGA, cex=0.9, font=2)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `text()` in the right way. Try something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)^2, label = LETTERS[1:10])
scatter.smooth(df$x, df$y)
text(df$x+.3, df$y, df$label)
```

[image]